# The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise - java android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I making an app using google drive to store files for user to their google drive
I followed google developer guide in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk
and when i press the button to upload my files i got the err in title
this is

## my code :

```
 try {
        // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                credentials);

        Drive service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();

        File fileMetaDate = new File();
        fileMetaDate.setName(getString(R.string.db_name_lists));
        File file1 = service.files().create(fileMetaDate, fileContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        Toast.makeText(this, file1.getId() + " has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## error

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise - java android

Answer (score 0):

To use

```
 GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
```

You must have the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

Other wise you can do it like shown in the [Google drive java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java#step_2_set_up_the_sample)

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
if (in == null) {
  throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
}
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
    GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: can u explain how and where to define GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and point it to a credentials file?
the https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java#step_2_set_up_the_sample not worked for me

Comment: Try googling  "how to set environmental variable in java".      Define "not working for me"

Comment: tnx for your guidance . i created environmental variable and set the path to json file that i get from google console  . a creadentials type OAuth 2.0 client IDs . but i still get the error . i'm really confused . how do i solve this problem?